# Why is squid breaking kerberos/NTLM auth?

Tags: squid, kerberos, ntlm

I'm using squid 2.6.22 (Centos 5 Default) as a proxy. Squid seems to break the authentication process for web pages when they require NTLM or Kerberos Auth.
I tested with sharepoint 2007 and tried all 3 authentication methods (NTLM, Kerberos, Basic).
Accessing the site without squid works in all cases. When I access the same page with squid, then only basic-auth works. 
Using IE or Firefox desn't make any difference. Squid itself can be used by anybody (no auth_param configured).
Its a bit tricky to find solutions online, since most of the topics whirl around auth_param for authenticating users to squid rather than authenticating users to a webpage behind squid.
Could anyone help?


**Edit:** 

Sorry, but my first test was totally screwed up. I tested against the wrong webservers (Memo to myself: always check assumptions before testing). Now I realized that the problem scenario is completely different.

- Kerberos work for IE
- Kerberos works for Firefox (after changing "network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris" in about:config)
- NTLM works for IE
- NTLM does NOT work in Firefox (even after changing "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" in about:config)

By the way:
The feature that provides NTLM-passthrough in squid is called "connection pinning" and the HTTP header "Proxy-support: Session-based-authentication""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Bug in Firefox, causing NTLM to fail in certain conditions. Using Squid as a proxy will almost always meet these conditions.
See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602814

Comment: Nice catch! Bug is closed, so it is present even in FF 11?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ask is very relative to [How to configure apache to basic authentication or allow when ntlm while proxying?](https://serverfault.com/a/345929/101556). In particular, if you want to authenticate both to proxy, and then to remote site, it is not possible (unless client uses `CONNECT`).

If your situation is that you don't want to authenticate to Squid, but only to remote site, then I think Squid is somehow doing the right thing: once the resource you have fetched by authenticating yourself is in cache, it is now available also for non-authenticated requests for other clients. More precisely, have a look at this flow:

- User A has requested the resource `/index.html` on some `that.server.com` and provided the authentication information.
- Server returned HTTP status 200 and Squid has cached the resource `/index.html`.
- Now user B has requested the same resource and has provided no authentication information / or has provided some authenticated information.

Possible scenarios:

- Squid returns `/index.html` to user B from cache. This is wrong, as only server knows which users have access to which resources.
- Squid also tries to cache the authentication information together with `/index.html`. For basic authentication Squid can capture the username. Other mechanisms (NTLM/Kerberos) send only hashes over HTTP, so there is no way to learn the username.
- Squid never caches `/index.html`.

Comment: Adding: It is not /Index.html may not be accessible to some users. It may look different depending on user.

Comment: I don`t think the Problem is related to caching. No well behaving Proxy will ever cache sites, where authentication is used. See: http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html for a good explanation.